# Charset string appended with dbname when using jdbc to connect to Mysql in Matlab

Tags: mysql, matlab, jdbc

I am trying to set the charset when letting Matlab connect to remote mysql database server.

The connection url is like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://host/mtdb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8
```

And after executing:

```
c = database("mydb", 'username', 'password','com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', "connection_string as above");
```

But Matlab throws an exception:

```
'Unsupported character encoding 'UTF8mydb'.
```

I cannot see why character encoding is appended with `"mydb"`. I don't see any syntax error in the connection url format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
dbURL = 'jdbc:mysql://localhost/mydb?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF8';
conn = database('', 'user', 'pass', 'com.mysql.jdbc.Driver', dbURL)
curs = exec(conn, 'select * from table')
```

Comment: @xiaohan2012: not really, you dont need to specify the database name in both places (instance and url)